# How to set spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema and spring.sql.init in CODE (not yml)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.batch

```
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
or
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
```

How do I set this in .java CODE (aka, "java config")...instead of application.properties or application.yml

I've tried setting properties of

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
```

with no luck.

I am using

```
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
```

in my "java config" class to create my connection to the jpa-backend-data-store.

other properties I'm trying to set in java-code ("java config")

```
"spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema", "always");
"spring.sql.init.enabled", "true");
"spring.sql.init.mode", "always");
```

More "context" for future readers:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#sql-script-datasource-initialization

> SQL Script DataSource Initialization
> The underlying method used to support schema.sql and data.sql scripts has been redesigned in Spring Boot 2.5. spring.datasource.* properties related to DataSource initialization have been deprecated in favor of new spring.sql.init.* properties. These properties can also be used to initialize an SQL database accessed via R2DBC.